# complicated multidimentional array process with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

im having a problem trying to process this array tried several different ways but none where right, here's the array

```
Array ( 
  [search] => Array ( 
    [response] => Array ( 
      [errors] => 
      [number_of_hotels] => 1 of 1 
    ) 
    [lr_rates] => Array ( 
      [hotel] => Array  ( 
        [hotel_ref] => 3116 
        [hotel_currency] => [U] => USD 
        [hotel_rooms] => Array ( 
          [room] => Array ( 
            [ref] => 6382 
            [type] => 1 
            [type_description] => Standard 
            [sleeps] => 8 
            [rooms_available] => 
            [adults] => 8 
            [children] => 
            [breakfast] => false 
            [dinner] => false 
            [description] => 
            [alternate_description] => 
            [rack_rate] => 82.01 
            [date] => 19/08/201220/08/201221/08/2012
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [formatted_date] => 19 August 201220 August 201221 August 2012 
            [price] => FullFullFull
            [hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull 
            [numeric_price] => FullFullFull
            [requested_currency] => GBPGBPGBP 
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [available_online] => false 
            [minimum_nights] => 1 
            [bed_type] => 
            [cancellation_policy] => 
            [cancellation_days] => 
            [cancellation_hours] => 
            [room_terms] => 
          )
          [room] => Array ( 
            [ref] => 6382 
            [type] => 1 
            [type_description] => Standard 
            [sleeps] => 8 
            [rooms_available] => 
            [adults] => 8 
            [children] => 
            [breakfast] => false 
            [dinner] => false 
            [description] => 
            [alternate_description] => 
            [rack_rate] => 82.01 
            [date] => 19/08/201220/08/201221/08/2012
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [formatted_date] => 19 August 201220 August 201221 August 2012 
            [price] => FullFullFull
            [hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull 
            [numeric_price] => FullFullFull
            [requested_currency] => GBPGBPGBP 
            [numeric_hotelcurrencyprice] => FullFullFull
            [available_online] => false 
            [minimum_nights] => 1 
            [bed_type] => 
            [cancellation_policy] => 
            [cancellation_days] => 
            [cancellation_hours] => 
            [room_terms] => 
          )
        ) 
        [cancellation_type] => First Night Stay Chargeable 
        [cancellation_policy] => 2 Days Prior to Arrival 

        [CityTax] => Array ( 
          [TypeName] => 
          [Value] => 
          [OptedIn] => 
          [IsCityTaxArea] => 
        )
      )
    )
  ) 
)
```

ok i need to traverse the array and create a loop so for every instance of room it will repeat the process then i need to extract the data from room array and use it to populate rows in MySQL there will be multiple instances of room this is the code i have so far which prints the names and values in the room array but it only gets one of the room arrays what can i do to set it up to read them all and i am also thinking this is too many for-each but don't seem to be able to traverse down ['']['']['']... 
or by just using the associative name.

```
foreach($arr['search'] as $lr_rates) {
        foreach($lr_rates['hotel'] as $hotel) {
                   foreach($hotel['room'] as  $field => $value){
                     print $field;print $value;
                          }

             }
      }
```

it mite also be worth mentioning the values in these arrays are always fluctuating

Comment: Wow - any chance you'd be able to fix that indentation nightmare?  I got nothing against horizontal scrollbars... but this is on another level :)

Comment: Please fix the array... I used to love 'waterslide' code but this is a classic example why it is bad.

Comment: just position yourself on the $array[a][b][c]...[room] and use a foreach from there on

Comment: or you could use 2 foreach's ; one to go until you reach the $key = 'room' and while in that $key, do another foreach ; eg: foreach( $array as $key => $value){ if( $key == 'room) { foreach( $value as $key2 => value2 ) { code here } ...

Comment: lonut Flavius Pogacian yes i think this is the correct way but i dont seem to be able to get it to work without throwing an error i gues ill have to try some different combinations of as $key => $value with the if conditions and some as $parentarray havent got it working yet though

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to use so much foreach loops in your script as it not looks good. this is an associative array.
you can simply access associate array by using its keys. do some google for it.you can find many scripts on this.

Comment: hi yea i tried that just using one foreach and the associative name now that would work in a flat array but it appears it doesn't in this case

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($arr as $search) {
    foreach($search as $lr_rates) {
        foreach($lr_rates as $hotel) {
                 foreach($hotel as $hotel_rooms) {
                      print_r($hotel_rooms['room'])
                  }
            }
     }
}
```

EDIT: These many `foreach` loops are just to make understand how to reach to `room`. You can also get the result directly ofcourse.

`print_r($arr['search']['lr_rates']['hotel']['hotel_rooms']['room']);`

Comment: that does output the room array however only one and throws errors prior to doing so